# Generic object wrapper

Tags: c++

I'm wondering if there's a good, generic way to write an object wrapper such that you could call all the methods defined by the class it wraps on the wrapper class itself (without having to explicitly redefine the class interface in the wrapper class).  For example, two different, arbitrary classes:

```
class InnerExample1 {
public:
    InnerExample1(int a, bool b) {...}
    void DoSomething1(int a) {...}
    bool DoSomething2(bool b) {...}
    etc...
};

class InnerExample2 {
    InnerExample2(float a, int b) {...}
    void DoWork(int a) {...}
    bool GetResult(bool b) {...}
    etc...
};
```

I'd like a generically defined wrapper class such that I could do:

```
Wrapper<InnerExample1> inner1;
inner1.DoSomething(42);
bool result = inner1.DoSomething2(false);
```

and

```
Wrapper<InnerExample2> inner2;
inner2.DoWork(21);
bool result = inner2.GetResult(true);
```

With 'Wrapper' being generic enough to be able to handle wrapper either class and forward all calls made on it to its inner delegate.

I've seen code for things like a factory pattern where, with variadic args, a generic factory could instantiate any class, as well as a generalizing a binding to a single member method, but nothing that's done it for the entire class.  It seems likely to me that it isn't possible...but people on SO come up with all sorts of stuff I never would have :)

EDIT:
I was trying to keep the question simple by leaving out unnecessary details, but I left out too many.  I need the wrapper to insert some logic around each call.  Say, for example, I want this wrapper to be able to count how many times each method has been called in addition to forwarding the call to the inner object.

EDIT2:
To be specific, I'm trying to write a generic wrapper to implement ActiveObject pattern.  I ended up doing an 'Active' base class that handles the common bits (managing the internal thread, queuing up function calls) and writing subclasses for each internal type (with their interface mimicked).

EDIT3:
@id256's answer is pretty interesting, I think I'll come back around at some point and give that method a try.

Comment: What about overriding `operator->()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is quite possible, you can define `operator->` inside the `Wrapper` class template. Actually this could look like:

```
template <typename T>
class Wrapper {
    T* pT;
public:
// ...
    T* operator->() { return pT; }
// all the needed stuff to manage pT
};
```

This approach is used in, for example, STL's `std::auto_ptr` implementation -- take a look at http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/auto_ptr/

EDIT: If you need to add some logic to calls via wrapper objects, the solution above is not acceptable. However you can try some functional features combined with templates (though the approach is rather tricky):

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>


class A {
public: 
    int inc(int x) {
        printf("A::inc %i\n", x);
        return x+1;
    }       
};      

template <typename _Function>
struct function_logged : public _Function {
    const char* log_msg;

    function_logged(_Function fun, const char* _log_msg)
    : _Function(fun), log_msg(_log_msg) { } 
};  

template <typename T, typename U, typename V, T (U::*mf)(V)>
function_logged<std::binder2nd<std::mem_fun1_t<T,U,V> > > create_function_logged(const V& arg, const char* log_msg) {
    return function_logged<std::binder2nd<std::mem_fun1_t<T,U,V> > >(std::bind2nd(std::mem_fun(mf), arg), log_msg);
}   

template <typename T>
class Wrapper {
    T* t; // pointer, not just a plain instance, because T may not have default constructor
public:
    Wrapper(T* _t) : t(_t) { }        

    template <typename T_mem_fun_tp>
    typename T_mem_fun_tp::result_type operator()(const T_mem_fun_tp& t_mf) {
        // Handle function object as you wish, for example print logging message
        std::cout << t_mf.log_msg << '\n';
        return t_mf(t);
    }   

    ~Wrapper() { delete t; }
};  

int main() {
    Wrapper<A> wA(new A());
    int y = wA(create_function_logged<int,A,int,&A::inc>(123, "calling A::inc from Wrapper"));
    std::cout << "wA.f(123)=" << y << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
calling A::inc from Wrapper
A::inc 123
wA.f(123)=124
```

EDIT2: In addition there's possible to override `operator->*` inside `Wrapper` and return some kind of proxy object, that holds a pointer to the instance and a pointer to the method. With this approach you can control the moment of method's execution, as well as pre- or post- process the proxy objects. A description of this technique can be found at http://aristeia.com/Papers/DDJ_Oct_1999.pdf

Comment: Indeed, definitely a solution if `wrapper` acting like a pointer (semantically) is acceptable.

Comment: I'll have to edit my post--I was trying to leave out details to keep things simple but guess I left out too many.  I need the wrapper class to be able to insert some extra logic for each call.

Comment: This is pretty interesting actually!  The only thing I see here is that the code in `function_logged` seems to assume the function will take a single argument?  If only std::mem_fun supported an arg pack that might do it.  Also, I was hoping to be able to have the wrapper do the bindings itself, so this would require the wrapper to know the return type/argument types for each of the functions.

Comment: STL provides only function objects, that wrap member functions wo parameters or with one parameter, but you can define a struct that holds all the parameters, though it isn't very elegant. If you want to automatically calculate return/argument type, you can write your own class template for this or use boost, that most likely provides some sort of such functionality.

Answer (score 2):

If you're not able to inherit from T you may overwrite the -> operator to give access to the wrapped class

```
class Wrapped { 
public: 
    void DoSomething(); 
}; 

template<class T>  
class Wrapper { 
public: 
    T * operator->() { 
        return &t; 
    } 

private: 
    T t; 
}; 

int main() { 
    Wrapper<Wrapped> w; 
    w->DoSomething(); 
}
```

Comment: As the OP stated in response to the answer below that proposes the same question, the problem is that they actually want the `Wrapper` to properly proxy the wrapped classes methods so that they can inject additional before/after operations into the method calls.

Answer (score 2):

It is not particularly encapsulated but you could use a function template that takes a member function pointer and a variadic argument pack:

```
template<typename Inner>
class Wrapper {
 private:
  Inner inner;
 public:

  template<typename ...Args>
  Wrapper(Args&&... args) : inner(std::forward<Args>(args)...) { }

  template<typename ...Args, typename R>
  R forward( R (Inner::* function)(Args...), Args &&...args) {
    return (inner.*function)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
  }
};


Wrapper<InnerExample1> wrapper1(1, true);
wrapper1.forward(&InnerExample1::DoSomething1, 42);
bool result = wrapper1.forward(&InnerExample1::DoSomething2, false);
```

<kbd>[Live demo](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/tUUFkG6n3JvywCcN)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

As per your comment(and edit), the closest you can get is to do some logic before a method is called(or an attribute is accessed), exploiting the fact that the operator-> has to be used with a method or attribute name on the right hand side. Unfortunately you have no way of telling which one it was.

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
class wrapper {
  T obj;
  public:
  T* operator->() {
    std::cout << "Method called(or attribute accessed). Can't tell which one." << std::endl;
    return &obj;
  }
};

struct wrapped {
  void do_nothing() {}
};

int main() {
  wrapper<wrapped> a;
  a->do_nothing();
}
```

Comment: I actually need to insert some logic in the wrapper class itself that will do some work for each method called though.

Comment: If you need to change behaviour of a method, there's no way around simply overiding it or use delegation. You mean do the **same** work for any method called(i.e.:writing to a logfile, for example)?

Comment: That's known as http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern

Comment: @c-smile reading up on CRTP, it looks like that would give me hooks for the ctor & dtor, but not each of the individual methods?

Comment: @bbaldino CRTP may allow you to define single wrapper that may do pred and post processing of called methods. But you will need to create individual methods in it that wrap each call.

Comment: @c-smile, while the code written(before edition) certainly resembled CRTP, it was not an example of it, if I'm not mistaken. To the OP: Edited answer.

Comment: Thanks @CássioRenan.  I was hopeful some template magic that eluded me might have been able to get this done.  I was actually trying to write a generic wrapper to implement ActiveObject pattern.  I was able to write a base class that has most of the generic logic, but guess I'll need to write specific subclasses for each internal class.

Comment: Note that `T obj;` is not the most universal solution, as T may not have a default constructor.

Comment: @id256 yes, of course. For brevity(And also because your answer covers this quite nicely), I'll keep it this way.